# What is the usage of " have have "?

Tags: grammar

I am reading an eBook. A sentence of that is as follows:

"I would like you to think about a piece of music that you ***have have*** found very peaceful and relaxing."

Why there are "have have" instead of "have" in that text? Isn't it a mistake?

Comment: It's just a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a mistake. The only verb form which can directly follow "have" is a past participle, so "have have" is not grammatical.